# How to create form tag dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to create div tag dynamically but unable to create form tag dynamically. the task is I have to create form tag in that i have to create div tag dynamically. Below is the code that create div tag dynamically

```
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(divTag).innerHTML = data;
```

Please help me to create form tag in that div tag dynamically using javascript

Comment: Have you tried something simple like `var formElement = document.createElement("form"); var divElement = document.createElement("div"); divElement.innerHTML = data; formElement.appendChild(divElement); document.body.appendChild(formElement);`?

Comment: Can you show the same code not working using JSFiddle ?

Comment: Please found the below code I used for creating form tag ---------  var formtag = document.createElement("form");
            formtag.id = "frmtag1";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
var formTag = document.createElement( 'form' );

divTag.innerHTML = data;
divTag.appendChild( formTag );

document.body.appendChild(divTag);
```

I don't know, what kind of data you assign to `innerHTML`, but the above code would append the `form` tag after that data.

---

Alternativly you could build up a whole string with all the content for that `div` and set `innerHTML` once.

```
var divTag = document.createElement("div");

data += '<form action=""></form>';

divTag.innerHTML = data;
document.body.appendChild(divTag);
```